# Why am I hitting a hard limit of 79 tables in my edmx?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-4

My team has an Oracle database with about 100 tables and 30 or so views.  Several weeks ago, we noticed while adding a new table from the DB to our Entity Framework data model (through the EDMX designer, update model from database wizard) that the update was hanging--on a couple of occasions it returned after about 15 minutes, but more often we killed Visual Studio or aborted the update.

I've experimented to see if I could isolate the problem.  I wiped out the old diagram, and all model entities.  I created a new diagram, and began adding tables--at first, one at a time, then 3, 4, or 5 at a time.  The first add took about 15 seconds to generate the model.

```
Loading metadata from the database took 00:00:00.5137297.
Generating the model took 00:00:14.8504157.
```

Each subsequent add (of 1-5 more tables) took a couple of seconds more.

```
Loading metadata from the database took 00:00:00.5682151.
Generating the model took 00:00:17.2365107.

Loading metadata from the database took 00:00:00.5065684.
Generating the model took 00:00:18.1086428.
```

At about 75 tables, adding another table or two took about 30 seconds.

```
Loading metadata from the database took 00:00:00.5524721.
Generating the model took 00:00:30.5682269.
```

At table number 80, there is an definite break point.  Trying to add the 80th table causes the designer to hang indefinitely.  I have to kill the wizard and abort the add.

I've tried removing other tables, then adding new ones, and the particular tables don't seem to matter--it's all about the number.

Even stranger is that I can add views--they don't seem to count toward this 80-table limit.

Anyone have any idea what's going on?

(My only guess is some configuration setting--connection pool limit, etc.  But I can't find anything that shows an '80'.)

Technical:

Visual Studio Pro 2012.

system.data.entity.dll, runtime v4.0.30319, version 4.0.0.0.

EntityFramework.dll runtime v4.0.30319, version 5.0.0.0  (<--is this a mismatch?)

Comment: Try splitting some of the tables into another diagram - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj519700.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any officially documented table limits with EF. But certainly I would think with a database this big, trying to load the edmx would probably crash due to memory reasons alone. There are a lot of questions on SO similar to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273342/entity-framework-with-lots-50k-tables), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778407/entity-framework-4-0-is-there-a-limit-on-the-number-of-objectstables-views-spr) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946561/is-entity-framework-good-for-bigger-database)

and possibly you should go through all of the solutions to find your fit of maybe working around this, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1273363/1081340).

Comment: "...with a database this big..." I think you must have misread.  Eighty or so tables is by no means a "big" database.